# Same network card for multiple composer rest server users

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I started composer rest server in multi user mode, using github oAuth authentication. I opened one session in chrome and one in firefox (to emulate as two different users) and authenticated using github. Now in one browser I wish to use one network card and in chrome another network card. Now when I import a network card in firefox same is reflected in Chrome as well. Doesn't it defeats purpose of authourisation ? So if one user is using its network card to perform transaction the other user will also be using the same network card as its been set as default for composer rest server. How to deal with scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is set at the **REST Client** - not the REST server. You're consuming the REST APIs as a client - as the two different blockchain identities (contained in each of your business network cards). Once a client has authenticated to the REST API, that client can add Blockchain identities to a wallet. The wallet is private to that client, and is not accessible to other clients. When a REST client makes a request to the REST server, a Blockchain identity in each clients wallet is used to digitally sign all transactions made by that client (because the identity is set as default, at the time).

The github authentication scheme is a 'delegated' authentication scheme and is using a client application (id and secret) authentication mechanism to enable a client to use the REST APIs and get a token, without needing to authenticate as a user every time.

Comment: So you mean to say I am getting the same network card in both browsers because I have authenticated same user via GitHub in both browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Configured the composer rest server with multi user using a jwt strategy, but I was seeing the same wallet (and the same default card) regardless of which user was logged in.

I found that the loopback-component-passport package which largely manages the wallet data was importing my users correctly, but they were all being associated with the same identity because the identity id was taken from the COMPOSER_PROVIDERS config and not the signing in user.

To fix it I modified loopback-component-passport/lib/models/user-identity.js.

Look in the UserIdentity.login method around line 100 where the userIdentity is being populated.

Change:

```
provider: provider,
```

to something like

```
provider: profile.sub,
```

depending on your payload / user profile.

After that each user will have their own identity registered in your loopback database and each signed in user should have their own wallet.